# Why is there is no auto-dereference for Weak<T>?

Tags: rust

The [`std::rc` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/index.html) says:

> `Rc<T>` automatically dereferences to `T` (via the `Deref` trait)

And also

> `Weak<T>` does not auto-dereference to `T`, because the inner value may have already been dropped.

So along with providing an option to `upgrade()` the weak pointer to return `Option<Rc<T>>` , if there's a `Deref` implementation in standard library on weak which returns `Option<T>` does it cause any issues?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> So along with providing an option to upgrade() the weak pointer to return Option> , if there's a Deref implementation in standard library on weak which returns Option does it cause any issues?

If you look at the definition of Deref you will see:

```rust
pub trait Deref {
    type Target: ?Sized;
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target;
}
```

So if we define `type Target = Option<T>` for `Weak` we have to return an `&Option<T>`, meaning we have to return a reference to an `Option` which lives elsewhere. Which `Weak` can't do because there's no `Option` living anywhere it could use for that.

There are further issues with this idea:

- `Option<T>` means the `Option` *owns* the `T`, which means we have to *move* the `T` out of the `Weak`, which is obviously nonsense (as a `Weak` doesn't own its item pretty much by definition).
- as there's no static relationship between an `Rc` and a `Weak`, assuming it were possible to deref' to `Option<&T>` instead you could get a dangling pointer by downgrading the Rc, getting a reference, then dropping the Rc: the `Weak` still exists, the `Option` can't change from under you, so you get a `Some(&T)` to a `T` which has been dropped.

That's why `upgrade` returns an `Rc`, this ensures that if you still had a living Rc when you called `upgrade` you're now keeping it alive independently.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it can be done. If that function existed, imagine this code:

```
let r: Rc<i32> = Rc::new(42);
let w: Weak<i32> = Rc::downgrade(&r);
let i: &i32 = w.unwrap(); //deref() -> Option<&i32>
drop(r);
let x: i32 = *i; //dangling reference, crash!!
```

To avoid this problem most [weak-reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/Reference.html#get()) or [weak-pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) [implementations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.weakreference.target?view=netcore-3.1#System_WeakReference_Target) require you to upgrade a weak reference to a normal one before using it. This is particularly important in a multithreaded scenario (`Arc` in Rust) because a `is_alive` check would mean basically nothing.